# Winsock recv all bytes

Tags: c++, networking, windows, tcp

I had some issues with sending huge data and receiving them with Winsock so I made some improvements on my `RecvAllBytes` function and the same with `SendAllBytes`. I would like you to review it because I made a lot of conditions and loops.  Please let me know how to improve the code below.

```
constexpr int maxBufferSize = 8192;

bool Server::RecvAllBytes(std::shared_ptr<Connection> connection, char * data, int totalbytes)
{
    int totalbytesreceived = 0;
    if (totalbytes > maxBufferSize)// if buffer is bigger then maximum allowed 
    {
        while (totalbytesreceived < totalbytes)//while full buffer not received 
        {
            int bytesrecv = 0;
            int bytesleft = totalbytes - totalbytesreceived;
            if (bytesleft >= maxBufferSize)// if there is still more left then maximum size keep recv full size
            {
                while (bytesrecv < maxBufferSize)
                {
                    int ReturnCheck = recv(connection->socket, data + totalbytesreceived, maxBufferSize - bytesrecv, NULL);
                    if (ReturnCheck == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    bytesrecv += ReturnCheck;
                    totalbytesreceived += ReturnCheck;
                }
            }
            else// if left less then maximum size recv last bytes left 
            {
                while (bytesrecv < bytesleft)
                {
                    int ReturnCheck = recv(connection->socket, data + totalbytesreceived, bytesleft - bytesrecv, NULL);
                    if (ReturnCheck == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    bytesrecv += ReturnCheck;
                    totalbytesreceived += ReturnCheck;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else // if buffer is not bigger then maximum allowed
    {
        while (totalbytesreceived < totalbytes) {
            int ReturnCheck = recv(connection->socket, data + totalbytesreceived, totalbytes - totalbytesreceived, NULL);
            if (ReturnCheck == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                return false;
            }
            totalbytesreceived += ReturnCheck;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding improving the code, here are some suggestions:

1. Reduce the number of conditions/loops. The whole method is doable in a single `while` loop. See below for an example.
2. Prefer nouns for names of variables and verbs for functions/methods. For instance, instead of calling the return value `ReturnCheck`, call it `ReturnValue`.
3. Refactor the code to handle the connection getting closed before getting all of the expected bytes. According to a [Microsoft Winsock web page for the `recv` call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx), "If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero". At which point I believe your code will try again and get `SOCKET_ERROR` (with an error code of `WSAENOTCONN`). And then return false even though it may have missed only say the last byte expected.
4. Recognize values that are constant with the C++ `const` type qualifier (or `constexpr` as you've done for compile-time constants).
5. Seeing as how you used `constexpr` (available since C++11), go ahead and also prefer using `auto`.
6. Consider making the `RecvAllBytes` method a method of a class that the client can use too (I don't demonstrate this though).

Here's how this could look (I didn't compile and test this code but hopefully it works):

```
int Server::RecvAllBytes(std::shared_ptr<Connection> connection, char * data, int bytesExpected)
{
    WSASetLastError(0);

    auto bytesReceived = decltype(bytesExpected){0};
    while (bytesExpected > 0)
    {
        const auto bytesRequested = (bytesExpected > maxBufferSize)? maxBufferSize: bytesExpected;
        const auto returnValue = recv(connection->socket, data + bytesReceived, bytesRequested);
        if (returnValue == -1 || returnValue == 0)
        {
            return bytesReceived;
        }
        bytesReceived += returnValue;
        bytesExpected -= returnValue;
    }
    return bytesReceived;
}
```

And how it could be used:

```
const auto bytesReceived = server.RecvAllBytes(connection, bigBuffer, bigSize);
if (bytesReceived < bigSize)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        // handle error.
    }
    else
    {
        // handle connection closed before all bytes received.
    }
}
```